# Javascript code not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new at using javascript, this is code that someone put into a C# ASP.Net website, It is supposed to get the city and state from a zip code entered. It works great in IE9, Chrome, Firefox, but fails in IE8. I have no idea as to why. Here is the javascript, I hope something stands out to someone. I also included the markup that uses it. I don't know where it is failing, I get the  Pcodefail result and '* Unable to find Postal Code' is displayed.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Pcodefail').hide();
    });
</script>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id$=uxPostalCode]').focus(function () {
            var city = $('[id$=uxCityState]');
            city.val('');
        });

        $('[id$=uxPostalCode]').blur(function () {
            var city = $('[id$=uxCityState]');
            var oCity = $('[id$=uxCity]');
            var oState = $('[id$=uxState]');
            $.getJSON("http://www.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?&country=US&callback=?", { postalcode: this.value }, function (response) {
                //$.getJSON("http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?postalcode=?&country=US&radius=10&username=demo", { postalcode: this.value }, function(response) {
                if (!city.val() && response && response.postalcodes.length && response.postalcodes[0].placeName) {
                    city.val(response.postalcodes[0].placeName + ', ' + response.postalcodes[0].adminCode1);
                    oCity.val(response.postalcodes[0].placeName);
                    oState.val(response.postalcodes[0].adminCode1);
                    $('#Pcodefail').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#Pcodefail').toggle();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="base-container-controls-100pct">
    <div class="base-container-controls-20pct">
        <div class="label-sm">Postal Code<span style="color: #ff0000; vertical-align: top">*</span>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="base-container-controls-50pct">
        <asp:TextBox ID="uxPostalCode" CssClass="textbox-sm" Text="" TabIndex="7" runat="server" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxreqValZip" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Postal Code" Font-Bold="False" Text="*" ValidationGroup="one" ControlToValidate="uxPostalCode"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <div id="Pcodefail" style="color: Red">* Unable to find Postal Code</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is jquery, what error messages do you get and where does it fail?

Comment: Please replace this with a description of the symptom (error message, unexpected behavior) and a short, self-contained, snippet of code that produces the problem.

Comment: I updated the code area with the markup that uses the javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but upon a cursory inspection of the code, the first thing that stands out is the tag `<script type="application/javascript">`. I'm fairly sure it should be `<script type="text/javascript">` instead. IE is very picky about JS tags.

Comment: Mark Elliot's answer as correct answer so he will get point. :)